# using axios data from Laravel pagination array

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

ok I am stumped and I know its going to be something stupid. So let me explain more in detail. The code above is what I believe should work for pagination from a Laravel controller to a vue component. I get that I am not fully accounting for pagination and I can handle that later but the first results are not available for use when I do this and I do not understand where my syntax is wrong.

Vue:

```
<ul role="list" class="space-y-4">
                <li
                    v-for="item in allActivities"
                    :key="item.id"
                    class="bg-gray-800 px-4 py-6 shadow sm:p-6 sm:rounded-lg"
                >
                    {{ item.description }}
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Mounted:

```
mounted() {
        axios
            .get("/activity")
            .then((response) => (this.allActivities = response.data));
    },
```

Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $activity = Activity::paginate(10);
        
        return $activity;
    }
```

If in the v-if I change it to allActivities.data it refreshes to show the data until I reload the page and get id not found.
If I change the axios to response.data.data it works, but I lose pagination.

IM stuck

Answer (score 0):

`response.data` is the result from laravel

`response.data.data` if the `data` key in the result which is a list of your models

`response.data` will contain these keys if using

current_page
data
first_page_url
from
last_page
last_page_url
links
next_page_url
path
per_page
prev_page_url
to
total

Comment: yes I know but the issue is when I change the v-for to include the .data, the page gives me a number of errors and wont load. Everything above makes sense to me both my code and your answer but it still doesn't fix why it isnt working. The end goal is to have pagination on the results with most likely an infinite scroll so I need all the data.

Comment: on first mount allActivities is null/undefined so you cant loop over .data

Comment: If I remove the pagination and just have all data - it works fine. This issue is only happening during pagination.

Comment: When using pagination laravel wraps the result in a data key, so you need to loop over response.data.data, when not using pagination your model result is response.data

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand the problem. If you want to change page, send the value of the page you want to display to the fetchActivities() method.

EDIT!

```
   <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          allActivities: {
            data: [],
            total: null
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        async fetchActivities(page = 1){
          const {data:activities} = await axios.get(`/activity?page=${page}`)
            this.allActivities.data.push(activities.data)
        this.allActivities.total = activities.total
        }
      },
      created() {
        this.fetchActivities()
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <div v-if="allActivities.data.length > 0">
        <ul role="list" class="space-y-4">
                    <li
                        v-for="(item, index) in allActivities.data"
                        :key="index"
                        class="bg-gray-800 px-4 py-6 shadow sm:p-6 sm:rounded-lg"
                    >
                        {{ item.description }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: The end goal is infinite scroll. So in your example you have activities.data - When I do that, the page wont load and I get the error data() doesnt exist, but...  I only get that on page reload. For that moment when I change it without a full page reload, I see the data

Comment: Why not just push activities to an array?

Comment: Your edit doesnt work either. I am not getting the data. Again, I can get all the data just fine, but the moment I add pagination into the response, everything breaks

Comment: Sorry, I can't make any inferences from what you said. Please share your code and the error you get with us.